# Grails 2.4.3, "resource is not available" in deployed war

Tags: grails, war

We have an application that works well when we run it via 'grails run-app'.
But when we build war and deploy it we get 404 error for any requested URL (e.g. "/index.gsp" not found).

What could be the reason?

```
grails run-app
```

OK

```
grails war
```

404 error, resource is not available

```
grails test run-war
```

404 error, resource is not available

Here is plugins configuration:

```
plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.7'
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"

    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.5" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.17"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

    // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
    //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
    //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
    //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
    //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
}
```

Comment: Post your plugins configurations, in your `Buildconfig.groovy`.

Comment: @vcarvalho, posted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by moving filters out of the package.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer little bit more? I am facing same scenarios against some resources.

Comment: @BilalAhmedYaseen check what filters you have (http://docs.grails.org/2.2.1/ref/Plug-ins/filters.html) and try to turn off/remove them. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

What is your development environment (Windows?) and what is your target environment (Unix, Linux?). I had to recompile my WAR file on my target environment (Linux) because I had similar issues with resources not found in my WAR file created in Windows.

Fortunately my Grails downloaded for Windows worked also on Unix (both need a JVM to run). So try copying your Grails to your target environment, and follow these steps:

1. `grails create-app your-project-name`
2. Copy all your original project files under the grails-app directory to your target environment, at least include the following:

   - assets
   - conf
   - controllers
   - domain
   - i18n
   - migrations
   - services
   - taglib
   - utils
   - views
3. `grails clean-all`
4. `grails refresh-dependencies`
5. `grails compile`
6. `grails prod war`

I suspect one of the libraries (like Oracle's ojdbc6.jar) depends on local system calls that need to be recompiled when moving to a different OS.

Hope that helps.

Comment: We have Windows as dev and Linux as test, but previous builds (war) were deployed successfully to target env.
Seems like this is not an issue, as build war does not work properly in Windows environment (when I run 'grails test run-war')

Comment: I agree, 'grails test' behaves quite differently than 'grails prod'. Maybe someone can enlighten us with what exactly needs to happen when running under 'test' mode.